# Where can I find the UK visa issue rate in South Asia?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I want to know the visa issuance rates by the UK for various South Asian countries.

1. over the years
2. since 2022

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information can be pieced together from the UK government websites. Obviously there is no data for 2022 (as it is currently 2022, so any data would be incomplete)  But there is data for 2021. It can be found in the data tables linked to https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics/immigration-statistics-year-ending-december-2021/how-many-people-come-to-the-uk-each-year-including-visitors

It gives

| Country | Work | Skilled work | Temp work | Study | Family | Visitor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| India | 70,099 98% | 64,839 >99% | 2,221 77% | 98,747 96% | 2,829 88% | 84,743 80% |
| Pakistan | 5,906 92% | 4,387 97% | 624 94% | 17,533 95% | 8,004 90% | 19,158 63% |
| Bangladesh | - | - | - | 10,999 97% | 1,708 87% | 4,666 61% |

In all cases the absolute value is followed by the percentage of approvals (out of the total number of applicants)

Other South Asian countries (Nepal, Bhutan, etc) the number of applications was not enough to place in the top 20 and isn't included in the data table.

For example, in 2021, 70099 work visas were granted to applicants from India, and 98% of those who applied were successful.

Comment: I haven't the inclination to do the same search for the USA.